# SvelteKit externalFetch function in hooks never gets called

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to modify my fetch request for external API to include a custom header. After trying multiple things, I saw externalFetch in the documentation which seems to serve the purpose of modifying the request but the problem is it never gets called. What am I missing?

```
export async function externalFetch(request) {
    request.headers['authorization'] = 'HMAC 12.33';
    console.log('hook headers', request);
    request = new Request(
        request
    );

    return fetch(request);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way to do it. If you want to add custom headers to a fetch call try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [fetch](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading#input-fetch) function that sveltekit provices you through the [load](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading#input) function in order for the `externalFetch` to trigger, here is an example from the sveltekit documentation:

```
<!-- src/routes/blog/[slug].svelte -->
<script context="module">
    /** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Load} */
    export async function load({ params, fetch, session, stuff }) {
        const response = await fetch(`https://cms.example.com/article/${params.slug}.json`);

    return {
        status: response.status,
        props: {
            article: response.ok && (await response.json())
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just add headers to the Request using your method because Request.headers is read only.  You need to use Request.headers.append().

```
export async function externalFetch(request) { 
    request.headers.append('Authorization', 'HMAC 12.33')
    console.log('Request Headers', request.headers);
    return fetch(request);
}
```

see Fetch API Headers documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers#examples